# My code (<select> tag) does not get the CSS effects

Tags: html, css

(Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExGU0.jpg) So, as you can see, the  tag is not getting the CSS properties correctly (like the name, age and number are). Could someone point out what is going wrong with my code so far? As I am new here on Stack Overflow, I would also like to know if I should have added more of my code on my post (I have just added what would be logically helpful, like the CSS styles and the tag itself). If I did that wrong, I will try to send you everything you need to help me.

```css
#dropdown {
  text-aling: center;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px;
}

input,
button,
select,
textarea,
.form-control {
  font-family: 'Open sans';
  padding: 4px;
  font-size: 70%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  opacity: 87%;
  border: 1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #f9eedd;
}
```

```html
<form id="survey-form">
  <div>
    <label id="name" for="name">Name<br>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name-label" value="" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
        </label>
    <br></br>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label id="email">Email (<span class="optional">optional</span>) <br>
        <input type="email" name="name" id="email-label" value="" placeholder="Enter your email" required="">
        </label>
    <br></br>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label id="number">Number<br>
        <input type="number" name="age" id="number-label" value="" placeholder="Age" min="10" max="99" required>
        </label>
    <br></br>
  </div>

  <p style="margin-top: -10px;">Define your current musical level:</p>
  <select id="dropdown" name="role" required>
    <option disabled="" selected="" value="">Select your level</option>
    <option value="student">Student</option>
    <option value="job">Full Time Job</option>
    <option value="learner">Full Time Learner</option>
    <option value="preferNo">Prefer not to say</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

I saw that select tag also getting the CSS properties, but if you want to use the same width on the Select tag like the other fields, you need to remove the width from the dropdown. Also If you want to add some other style properties specifically only on the Select tag or any other specific tag, then you can write the CSS properties like the following way:

```
select#dropdown {
   border: 1px solid transparent;
   border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
   font-family: Arial;
   text-align: center;
   /* Write Other properties.....*/
}
```

Also here I am sharing one [resource](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_form.asp) for your reference so that you can make a responsive form using CSS

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know what is the problem with the "<select>"  for not applying the CSS properties correctly in my case? Because if you take a look at this form: https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/pen/VPaoNP, it works perfectly. If you check it out, you will see that he did the same thing that I did, but it worked.

Comment: I took code whatever you have attached in the question and it's worked for me. Still it's not working for you? Can you please attached the full source code with me? I will review the code again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you only specify `border-width`
add `border: 1px solid red;`

```css
#dropdown {
  text-aling: center;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input,
button,
select,
textarea,
.form-control {
  font-family: 'Open sans';
  padding: 4px;
  font-size: 70%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  opacity: 87%;
  border: 1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #f9eedd;
}
```

```html
<form id="survey-form">
  <div>
    <label id="name" for="name">Name<br>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name-label" value="" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
      </label>
    <br></br>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label id="email">Email (<span class="optional">optional</span>) <br>
      <input type="email" name="name" id="email-label" value="" placeholder="Enter your email" required="">
      </label>
    <br></br>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label id="number">Number<br>
      <input type="number" name="age" id="number-label" value="" placeholder="Age" min="10" max="99" required>
      </label>
    <br></br>
  </div>

  <p style="margin-top: -10px;">Define your current musical level:</p>
  <select id="dropdown" name="role" required>
    <option disabled="" selected="" value="">Select your level</option>
    <option value="student">Student</option>
    <option value="job">Full Time Job</option>
    <option value="learner">Full Time Learner</option>
    <option value="preferNo">Prefer not to say</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Your snippet CSS has a typo, is this just from copying or is this in your code?  `aling` should be `align`